Why is a TS80005 error showing up in my TS code?
index.ts
const utils = require("./utils.ts");

console.log(utils.sqrtRoot("asd"));

utils.ts
function sqrtRoot(x: number): number {
  return Math.sqrt(x);
}

module.exports = {
  sqrtRoot,
};

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
  }
}

package.json
{
  "name": "untitled",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.5.5",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2"
  }
}

Here are my findings:

On index.ts, at the require, I'm getting a TS80005. Why? I've clearly specfied this as a CommonJS project.
TS is breaking at the require. utils has no type data, and I can pass any datatype into the utils.sqrtRoot. No error from my IDE IntelliSense, or from the Compiler. It compiles with no errors.

What am I doing wrong?
I expect TS80005 to not be there, and for my IDE Intellisense or TSC to show me an error trying to pass a string into utils.sqrtRoot().


TS80005: 'require' call may be converted to an import.
Category: Suggestion

Source: microsoft/TypeScript

This is not an error, but a suggestion. TypeScript indicates that it may be beneficial to use a more modern import based on ES6 modules.

microsoft/TypeScript #28825 - Allow ignoring certain TS suggestion-level diagnostic codes
microsoft/vscode #46590 - Allow disabling TS suggestions level diagnostics

Alternative Solutions

Ignoring suggestions: You can simply ignore the suggestions if they do not interfere with your work. Since these are not errors, they won't prevent your code from running during compilation.

Accept suggestion: It might be worth updating your code to the ES6 style to avoid the suggestions. (It's generally a good idea to use a JavaScript build tool (e.g. Vite, Webpack, etc.) that allows you to generate any type of output code, including CommonJS, from your source code written in ES6. This way, your source code will remain fully modern and meet the current standards.)



TS doesn't allow require with TS modules unless they’re transpiled to JS first, you can still use require but you'll have to change every import/export file extension from .ts to .js.
As a side question, what's the purpose though?

can you please send me your source for this? from what you're saying, you literally can't use a TS file if it's CJS.
purpose - just learning TS :)

I suggest you read this piece:https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#esModuleInterop
and consider reading the documentation for better clarity.
